# What could cause a Java TCP socket to close?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to use an implementation of an MQTT client specifically [Paho Java client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) in Android, and trying to trace where I get an [EOFException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html)  error.

Specifically this happens on `in.readByte();`.

```
public final byte readByte() throws IOException {
    int temp = in.read();
    if (temp < 0) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
    return (byte) temp;
}
```

Having looked at this exception, it seems to be triggered when I'm attempting to read from a socket that has been closed. This seems to be a network error, that I fail to locate.

My question is what could cause a socket to close? I haven't yet ruled out the chance of it being closed programmatically but in case of an external factor what are the usual causes of a TCP socket closing? Perhaps any more specific reason relating to an Android device?

Comment: There could be several reasons - your broker is actually down, your network got disconnected, you actually closed the stream, you actually got a invalid EOF to name a few. Most of the cases it's a programmatic closure (accidental) or some error which is on the network side. The brokers are usually robust. Can you check if your `in` is valid and also log monitor the broker for what's being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the things that cause a socket to close are:

- the client closes the socket
- the server closes the socket, possibly due to a timeout
- the server shuts down and issues a reset, either before shutdown or after restart, which closes the socket
- a firewall times the connection out and effectively closes the socket by issuing a subsequent reset

Without more details on your specific symptoms, it's hard to say which of these is most likely.